# Display multiple lines (<p> tags) as a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I want to display multiple lines for example:

1. This is first sentence.
2. This is second sentence.
3. This is third sentence.

These three sentences need to displayed as -

```
This is first sentence. This is second
sentence. This is third sentence
```

Sample html for this could be

```
<p id="line-1"></p>
<p id="line-2"></p>
<p id="line-3"></p>
```

The use case is I need to track and save changes done in each sentence and save them seperately.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want to shome have some `<p>` tag at one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<body>
    <p>
        <span>This is first sentence. This is second
        sentence. This is third sentence</span>
    </p>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: <div class="para">
      <span contentEditable>This is sentence 1.</span>
      <span contentEditable>This is sentence 2.</span>
      <span contentEditable>This is sentence 3.</span>
    </div>

This seem to work for me to display as paragraph with noticeable UI inconsistencies. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Attach style display: 'inline-block' | 'inline'

```
<p id="line-1" style="display: inline"></p>
<p id="line-2" style="display: inline"></p>
<p id="line-3" style="display: inline"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `</br>` to split the statements in different lines.

```html
<body>
    <p id="line-1">1. This is first sentence.</br></p>
    <p id="line-2">2. This is second sentence.</br></p>
    <p id="line-3">3. This is third sentence.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sentence could be given inside a span as it is an inline container used to mark up a part of a text, or a part of a document.

```html
<div>
    <p>
        <span>This is first sentence. This is second
        sentence. This is third sentence</span>
    </p>
<div>
```